# How can I configure Kotlin coroutines for Gradle with the Kotlin DSL?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Using Gradle 4.4.1 with the Kotlin-DSL, I want to configure the experimental Kotlin coroutines in my Kotlin 1.2.20 project. This proves to be surprisingly difficult.

The official Kotlin documentation itself only mentions [Gradle with the Groovy DSL](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/diagnostics/experimental-coroutines.html) instead of Kotlin.

The Kotlin-DSL project has an [example for coroutines](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/master/samples/hello-coroutines/build.gradle.kts) that does not work. Probably, it’s for an older Gradle version (the Kotlin version in that script is 1.1.51, which is suspicious in itself).

PS: Even IntelliJ’s *configure Kotlin* writes incorrect Gradle code. Is downgrading the only option?

---

Addendum: The build script was *very red* in IntelliJ IDEA. The IDE kept adding import statements all the time. It seems that these futile attempts were what made the script non-functional. I disabled ‘Add unambiguos imports on the fly’ temporarily, and even though the script remained mostly red, Gradle could execute it. And afterwards, the error notices withing IntelliJ were gone as well.

Comment: For me it works like shown in the linked example. What is not working for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the `kotlin` plugin applied to the project:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.Coroutines

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm")
}

kotlin { // type is KotlinJvmProjectExtension
  experimental.coroutines = Coroutines.ENABLE
}
```

This works for me with Gradle 4.4.1 and 4.5-rc-1, and I should also work for versions before that. If you are bringing in the Kotlin plugin by using `buildscript` instead of `plugins`, you may not have the generated accessors and will have to use `extensions.getByType(KotlinJvmProjectExtension::class.java).apply {}` (or something like that).

Comment: what is meant by having the `kotlin` plugin applied to the project?

Comment: @Thufir I just meant that I am assuming you are applying a Kotlin plugin using the `plugins {}` block, because that is how the `kotlin` accesor is generated.

Comment: a plugins block is different from an apply block with a plugin?  If so, that may have solved my (different) problem...

Comment: In the current versions of the `kotlin-dsl`, yes.